# bootstrap styles interfering with grid-box in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid

I wanted to make a grid, but the first element(img) is not appearing in the first position, but appears in the second position. First image spot is left blank. I inspected the cause of this, and it seems that the styles from the bootstrap link `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">` are not letting my grid-box work properly, if i remove it, my navbar doesn't work.

Check out the code here: [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7rf9udLc/5/)

Please suggest a fix. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **bootstrap 3** uses **float** , it also uses pseudo elements to clear floats.

here a pseudo `.container:before{display:table;content:" "}` fills up the first cell, reset order to put it last . https://jsfiddle.net/nhak72r1/

```css
/* fix update */

.container::before {
  display: none;  /* hide it */
  order: 1;  /* set it last , if you already use order for other element, set the highest value for it */
}


/* end update */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.container>img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.container>img:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Chairs</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="head">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="brand-name" href="3">Chairs<span id="dot">.</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">News<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">What's New?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">New Discounts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/82/25/e1822536694c06c60d0df0897d7117e5.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/82/25/e1822536694c06c60d0df0897d7117e5.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/82/25/e1822536694c06c60d0df0897d7117e5.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/82/25/e1822536694c06c60d0df0897d7117e5.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2c/6e/3f/2c6e3f6d0cfbe5038a0ca7659c0eab46.jpg">


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```